# how does an update work? is it a transaction?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions, updates

I have this table:

```
Mytable(ID, IDGroupReference, Model ...)
```

I have many records in MyTable. The belong to a group, so all the records that belong to the same group has the the same IDGroupReference. IDGroup reference is the ID of one of the records that belong to the group. So all the records of a group has the same IDGroupReference, I can get all the records of the group with a single query:

```
select * from MyTable where IDGroupReference = 12345;
```

I can change one record from one group to another, in this case I want to change also all the records of the group too. I mean, I want to merge two groups in one.

In this case I can use this query:

```
Update Mytable set IDGroupReferencia = myIDReferenceGroup1 where IDGroupReference = IDGroupReferencieGroup2
```

I set the IDGroupReference of the group 2 with the IDGroupReference of the group one.

My doubt is about the concurrency, when two users try to change the group of two different records. Imagine the I have the group 1 with 10.000 records and tow users. User 1 try to change the record A of the group 1 to group 2 and user 2 try to change the record B from group 1 to group 3.

How the group has many records, 10.000, I think that when I try to update IDGroupReference with the query that I describe above, SQL Server update one by one, and how there are many records, it's is possible that some records are in the group b and other records go are in the group 3, when all of the must be in the same group, in the group 2 or 3, depends of which user is the last to update. But all of the records must be in the same group, not split.

So, when I use the update, how does it work? is a transaction and nobody can update any of the records that will be affected or a second user can update records in the middle of the update of the first user?

I mean:

group 1 with 10 records. User one execute the update. So the steps are:

- SQL Server updates record 1.
- SQL Server updates record 2

Meanwhile, a second user execute the query.

it is possible that the second user update the record 3 before is update by the query of the first user? Because if this happends, then the group 1 is splitted in two groups, some records go to group 2 and some of them go to group 3.

How can I ensure that all the records of the group 1 go to group 2 or group 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the hints of SQL Server. [In this link there are more information.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

The initial update:

```
Update Mytable set IDGroupReferencia = myIDReferenceGroup1 where IDGroupReference = IDGroupReferencieGroup2
```

It ss modify to:

```
Update Mytable with(tablock) set IDGroupReferencia = myIDReferenceGroup1 where IDGroupReference = IDGroupReferencieGroup2
```

By default SQL Server, with the update, only block the record that is being updated, but the rest can be modified. So I need to block all the table, to avoid that other update modify records in the middle of other update process.

The use of "with(tablock)" makes that, block the table when an update begins. then search for all the records that match with the where and update it. When the table is block, no other user can select or update records from this table. that is what I need in my particular case.